# Struggling to convert string to Dict in python

Tags: python, boto3, aws-ssm

I am using [boto3](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) to make a [ssm](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.get_parameter) call. I make a call like this.

```
import boto3
import json
ssm = boto3.client("ssm")
ssm.get_parameter(Name="slack_webhook")["Parameter"]["Value"]
```

The response I get is a string text that looks like this.

```
'Value\n{\n"progress-updates":  "https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0JExxxU6A6Q/xxxxxxxxx/pS7FvL1bIGZggKhLQvWsLAcV",\n"test-channel": "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/IXnWw4sLN5GjI324glzfUIdM",\n"prod": "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxx/xxxxx/xgtsgdgsdgsdgdsgs"\n}'
```

So when I do the following

```
json.loads(ssm.get_parameter(Name="slack_webhook")["Parameter"]["Value"])
```

I get the following error

> JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 json.loads(ssm.get_parameter(Name="slack_webhook")["Parameter"]["Value"])
>
> /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/pipeline/lib/python3.7/json/**init**.py
> in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int,
> parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
> 346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
> 347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
> --> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
> 349     if cls is None:
> 350         cls = JSONDecoder
>
> /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/pipeline/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py
> in decode(self, s, _w)
> 335
> 336         """
> --> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
> 338         end = _w(s, end).end()
> 339         if end != len(s):
>
> /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/pipeline/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py
> in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
> 353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
> 354         except StopIteration as err:
> --> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> 356         return obj, end
>
> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I would highly appreciate help in this matter. Do I need to clean up the string further by removing all the `\n`? because I tried it and did not work too.

Comment: remove the first "Value" string which makes the json string illegal

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because of the leading `Value`. Assuming the `Value` string is part of the response, you can write a simple function to trim off leading keys:

```py
def parse_json(x):
    first_brace = x.find("{")
    if first_brace == -1:
        raise ValueError(f"Does not look like a JSON: {x}")
    x = x[first_brace:]
    return json.loads(x)


>>> parse_json(x)
{'progress-updates': 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0JExxxU6A6Q/xxxxxxxxx/pS7FvL1bIGZggKhLQvWsLAcV',
 'test-channel': 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/IXnWw4sLN5GjI324glzfUIdM',
 'prod': 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxx/xxxxx/xgtsgdgsdgsdgdsgs'}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a valid JSON string contained in the response.

```
'{
"progress-updates":"https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0JExxxU6A6Q/xxxxxxxxx/pS7FvL1bIGZggKhLQvWsLAcV",
"test-channel":"https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/IXnWw4sLN5GjI324glzfUIdM",
"prod": "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxx/xxxxx/xgtsgdgsdgsdgdsgs"
}'
```